# Typesetting unit-less numbers and number-less units

Tags: siunitx, units

I am using the `siunitx` package to typeset my numbers, but sometimes I find situations in which I have numbers without units (when the units are not nearby) and units without numbers. E.g.:

```
The bird can fly 40 to 50 km per hour.

The data in the table above uses kg.
```

What is the prefered way to typeset these?

```
The bird can fly $40$ to $\SI{50}{\kilo\meter\per\hour}$.

The bird can fly \num{40} to \SI{50}{\kilo\meter\per\hour}.

The bird can fly \SI{40}{} to \SI{50}{\kilo\meter\per\hour}.

The data in the table above uses kg.

The data in the table above uses \SI{}{\kilo\gram}.
```

If find achieving visual consistency and correctness in the output is more important than having consistent, context-intelligent code.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To typeset units without numbers, you can use `\si{<unit>}` (note the lower case).

The mathematically correct way to typeset ranges of values with units is to include the unit with each of the numbers. This is what the command `\SIrange{<lower>}{<upper>}` does. If you don't want to repeat the units, you can set `[range-units = single]`.

Note that the most common units can be accessed using abbreviations (like `\km` for `\kilo\metre`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
The bird can fly \SIrange{40}{50}{\km\per\hour}.

The bird can fly \SIrange[range-units=single]{40}{50}{\km\per\hour}.

The data table above uses \si{\kg}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about "The bird can fly 40 *or* 50 km/h?"

Comment: You can use the `\SIlist{}` command: `\SIlist[list-pair-separator = { or }, list-units=single]{40; 50}{\kilo\meter\per\hour}`.